# Is this possible to upgrade HTC Desire to 2.3?

Tags: android

I have HTC Desire which runs on Android 2.1 (Eclair) platform now i want to upgrade this phone to 2.3(Gingerbread). I searched on Internet but not found any official release for this particular model for up-gradation to 2.3 but found some [articles ([1](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/download-official-htc-desire-android-2-3-gingerbread-update/),[2](http://androidcommunity.com/htc-desire-android-2-3-gingerbread-update-released-20110801/),[3](http://www.techobserver.org/5202.android-2-3-update-for-htc-desire-not-possible.html))] which says not possible to upgrade or some says after doing this process some functions are not working properly like SMS , WiFi features .Please suggest mein is it possible or not . If yes so please suggest me how can i upgrade this particular model to Android 2.3. Please share some link which shows steps or process for up-gradation. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you should ask this Question on any other site.Then you can get more experienced advice

Answer (score 1):

If it's not officially update you have to install a ROM.

The best place to find any kind of good ROM it's on [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=628).

I also recommend you [Cyanogen MOD](http://www.cyanogenmod.com) one of the most known ROM :)
HTC Desire is supported in both version:

- [HTC Desire GSM](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices/htc-desire-gsm)
- [HTC Desire CDMA](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices/htc-desire-cdma)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read this : 
http://www.forum-htc-dev.net/
http://www.forum-htc-dev.net/f87-dsr-roms-customs

Indeed it's possible to tun 2.3 on Desire, thanks to CyanogenMod as an exemple : 
http://www.forum-htc-dev.net/t42239-rom-234-aosp-4-08-2011toutes-versions-cyanogenmod-v7-nightly-152-et-stable-710-rc1

Carefull, don't try to do it too fast. Read all, then choose. 
- First, you must root your tel (exemple here http://unlockroot.com/unlockroot.php)
- Flash your Radio and recovery
- Flash your ROM
Done.

Have fun!

Comment: Oooups right, my links are in french :). See bellow for XDA link, that's good.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have:
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/HTC_Desire_%28GSM%29

But have in mind that this is not the official rom, so you will no longer have warranty on you cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at the custom mods. For instance, you can download and install CyanogenMod 7 for your Desire. My friend uses this mod. It is based on 2.3.x version of Android.